# How operating system understands if a thread has finished?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduler

When we start a thread Operating System puts that thread to run queue, and operating system's scheduler run that thread when the time(quantum) comes,
so how operating system understands if that thread has finished it's operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread calls an OS-specific function.  That function tells the OS that its done.  In most languages/frameworks this will be done behind the scenes for you.

Comment: But how? We only pass method reference when starting the thread, does os inject code at the end of thread function code?

Comment: You pass a method to the OS. The OS calls it. When it returns, the OS/framework function that called it then calls the os thread finished function

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two mechanisms for terminating kernel threads. They are the same as for terminating processes.

1. An explicit call to a system service to terminate the thread; or
2. An implicit call to a system service to terminate that is invoked when the thread's main function exits.